# The "select" element and cross browser transmitting of the data

Tags: html, cross-browser

I've always provided a `value="something"` for my `option` elements within a `select` element.

Like so

```
<select>
   <option value="true">True</option>
</select>
```

Now that I have made one with countries, there is a lot of extraneous data in there. I'm pretty sure if I remember correctly, that Firefox will send the text between the tags if a value attribute is not present.

My question is, is this behaviour the norm? Can I rely on all browsers sending the innerHTML of the option element if the value attribute is omitted?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will work in all browsers.

[As the specification says:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION)

> #### OPTION Attribute definitions
>
> `value = cdata [CS]`
>             This attribute specifies the initial value of the control. If this attribute is not set, the initial value is set to the contents of the OPTION element.

Answer (score 1):

Grabbed from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6):

> value = cdata [CS]
>       This attribute specifies the initial value of the control. If this
>   attribute is not set, the initial
>   value is set to the contents of the
>   OPTION element.

With this I'd think that every major standard compliant browser should take the 'value' attribute and if it's not present take the element